# How to mirror local tags to remote

Tags: git, bash

There are hundreds of Git tag questions on SO, but I couldn't find this one.

How can I mirror my local git tags to remote.

That is:

1. No matter what the original status of `origin`
2. I'd like to have a bash function which mirrors all local tags to the remote.
3. This includes synchronising if a tag was created, deleted or moved locally.

The opposite of this script is found everywhere, but for this direction I couldn't find anything.

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
git fetch --tags
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 is relatively easy, part 2 is less easy, and part 3 is impossible in general, because there's just not enough information recorded.

Here is an example.  You check repository *L* (which you have locally), and find that tag T1 exists, T2 does not, and T3 exists.

You now check repository *O*, the one at *L*'s origin, and find that tag T1, T2, and T3 all exist.

Which actually happened: "tag T2 did exist at *L* and was explicity deleted" or "tag T2 never existed at *L*, but was added in some way to *O*"?

Since Git does not save this kind of data, there is no way to tell whether T2 was explicitly deleted, or just never picked up.

If your requirement is simpler—if you don't *care* whether T2 was added to *O*, you just need to make *O* have *L*'s tags regardless of why *L* has those tags and not some other tags—then all you need to do is the same thing the two line script does, but in the other direction: first, delete all the tags (but on *O*, not on *L*), and then—second—push all the tags from *O* to *L*, with `git push --tags` or equivalent.

It's easiest to delete *O*'s tags on the machine that hosts *O* itself, but assuming you are not worried about atomicity issues, you can do it from *L*:

```
git ls-remote origin 'refs/tags/*'
```

(which will get you all the tags that are on `origin`), then:

```
git push --delete origin refs/tags/T1 refs/tags/T2 ...
```

(repeat for all tags), then:

```
git push --tags origin
```

Note that `git ls-remote` shows both the tag object names and their ultimate target objects:

```
7446b8fa5ead8ce0990e8f2be3a2490eac8e199f        refs/tags/v2.9.0
05219a1276341e72d8082d76b7f5ed394b7437a4        refs/tags/v2.9.0^{}
7590ed7abf57429b36761c00377a3648630029bd        refs/tags/v2.9.0-rc0
3a0f269e7c82aa3a87323cb7ae04ac5f129f036b        refs/tags/v2.9.0-rc0^{}
c93578b0c65ac46bb6bba0750542798518f09335        refs/tags/v2.9.0-rc1
60bd4b1c513bb652cdffad44382046ca872140eb        refs/tags/v2.9.0-rc1^{}
```

so this requires a little bit of filtering; and if you can force-push to overwrite tags, you can make this more efficient by doing a push with `+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` as the main refspec, and some `:refs/tags/xyz` auxiliary refspecs to delete any "extraneous" tags (like `T2` in my example above).  That requires a slightly smarter script.  A dumb-and-simple way is to print only unsuffixed tags, e.g.:

```
git ls-remote origin 'refs/tags/*' | awk '/\^{}$/ { next } { print $2 }'
```

which you can then pipe to `xargs git push --delete origin`.